# Redis cache errors for any command tried

Tags: azure, redis

I am getting the message 'error' for any new redis cache I deploy in Azure. This is not a timeout error. Did anyone experience this issue and have an idea on how to resolve this.

[image: Console errors]

Details same as above

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue.  I think it's an Azure issue.